# Did I get scammed buying this "vintage film negative"

Tags: film, negative-film, professional

I purchased a "vintage 8 x 10 film negative" of Shirley Temple on eBay supposedly from someones collection. I had assumed that by film negative it must be the actual film used in the camera to take the original photo. Therefore it would be a unique, one of a kind item. But as soon as I made the purchase, the seller listed the exact same item again. I'm no photographer. Is there a valid reason a photographer in the 1940's would have multiple copies of the same negative? Or is this seller making copies and scamming people?

Comment: I'm not really sure that this question is a good fit for here.  The only "photographic" element here is the fact that the item you bought from eBay was a negative.  But I'm not sure what a better forum would be, especially if the fundamental question is  establishing provenance of something.

Comment: Google found about 10 hits for "vintage 8 x 10 film negative Shirley Temple" all on eBay. All the ones I looked at actually showed a positive image - & very clean.  All in the $10 - 15 range, which wouldn't even buy you a new unexposed 8x10 negative these days.  If it quacks like a duck….

Comment: the seller's watermark on the negative sample is inverted from the photo positive sample, therefore, it seems _highly_ likely that they simply inverted the photo, at least for the listing, if not for the actual transparency they're selling (a hunch).

Answer (score 2):

"Vintage film negative" isn't the same as "Original vintage film negative". It is possible to duplicate negative film, see [here](https://www.nedcc.org/free-resources/preservation-leaflets/6.-reformatting/6.2-duplication-of-historical-negatives) for some techniques.

However, the result you get is probably not on a film of vintage manufacture, and you can perhaps use that as a reason to claim a refund.